# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión «La primera, en la frente»?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

Es una expresión para indicar que nada más empezar, algo ha salido mal. Por ejemplo:

> Luis.— En cuanto me bajé del andén, me robaron la maleta.
>
> Juan.— La primera, en la frente.

¿Alguien conoce el origen de esta expresión?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extraído de "[Breve instrucción de como se ha de administrar el sacramento de la penitencia](https://books.google.es/books?id=6h88AAAAcAAJ&pg=RA14-PR1&dq=%22la+primera+en+la+frente%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYkIK2hsHPAhUGORQKHXCRBFUQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22la%20primera%20en%20la%20frente%22&f=false)" (1581):

> "[...] todo fiel christiano esta obligado a tener devocion con la santa cruz de Jesucristo nuestro señor [...], y por tanto nos hemos de acostumbrar, a signar y santiguar, haziendo tres cruzes. **La primera en la frente**, porque nos libre Dios de malos pensamientos. **La segunda en la boca**, porque nos libre Dios de malas palabras. **La tercera en los pechos**, porque nos libre Dios de malas obras [...]"

Esta forma de <strike>[santiguarse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XGAuHt5)</strike> [signarse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xr7vCdE) aparece no solamente en este texto, sino en muchos textos religiosos desde el siglo XVI (y posiblemente antes) hasta ahora, para enseñar a la gente la forma correcta de hacerlo, repitiendo la expresión "la primera en la frente". De hecho, ha llegado hasta la definición actual de la RAE:

> 4. tr. Hacer con los dedos índice y pulgar de la mano derecha cruzados, o solo con el pulgar, tres cruces, **la primera en la frente**, la segunda en la boca y la tercera en el pecho, pidiendo a Dios que nos libre de nuestros enemigos. U. t. c. prnl.

Visto así, es normal que cuando te pasaba algo malo y tuvieras tendencia a los malos pensamientos, palabras u obras, te santiguaras para evitarlo, o que tu interlocutor te dijera "la primera en la frente" para que supieras por dónde tenías que empezar a santiguarte.

Curiosamente, uno de los significados de "santiguarse" es "[**hacerse cruces**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BOPN2zP)", lo cual significa "demostrar la admiración o extrañeza que causa algo", expresión apropiada también para la situación del ejemplo, y que podría explicar también el origen de la expresión. Esta expresión aparece ya en el primer diccionario de la RAE (de autoridades, 1729), y pone como ejemplo el Quijote:

> "Llegó Sancho, y como vió el rostro del Bachiller Carrasco, comenzó a hacerse mil cruces, y à santiguarse otras tantas."

Comment: Excelente respuesta! No lo había relacionado nunca, pero me acordé de la canción [Cruz de Navajas](http://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=24958) de Mecano: "sobre Mario, de bruces, tres cruces:/una en la frente, la que más dolió"

Answer (score 2):

Estoy de acuerdo con la excelente respuesta de Carlos Alejo, sobre el origen de la expresión. Pero para mayor precisión quisiera matizar que la forma de hacer la [**señal de la cruz**](http://elprotocoloenlasantamisa.blogspot.com.es/p/santiguarse-y-persignarse.html) descrita parece que se denomina "**signar**" o "**persignar**"

> ... lo hacemos con la yema del dedo pulgar de la mano derecha, haciendo pequeñas cruces respectivamente sobre la frente, los labios y el corazón...,

Comment: ¡Gran respuesta! Desde el momento que es un dato tangencial a la pregunta, también tienes la opción de hacer una pregunta del tipo _¿Qué diferencia hay entre persignar y santiguarse?_ y contestarla tú mismo con esta publicación.